# Combining ARRAYFORMULA and SUMIF to summarize Google Form responses

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Form linked to a Google Sheet. The form consists of twenty questions, all of which are answered by a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 response. In the sheet, there are 20 columns that correspond to the questions. Each row is the response of one subject.

Now the tricky part: there are six additional columns that sum all the 0's, 1's, 2's, 3's, 4's, 5's. For example, if a subject answers three of the questions with a value of 3, the value of 9 will populate the "3" column. I have been successful using the `SUMIF` formula, but copying and dragging down the column doesn't work because of the Google Form integration.

I understand the premise of array formulas, and I have discovered that it doesn't work with `SUMIF`.

I have spent the better part of two days searching for solutions including combining `SUM` and `FILTER`, `HLOOKUP`, and `MMULT`. I just can't solve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating functions such as sum() will not produce multi-cell results in an arrayformula() wrapper.

Some other aggregating functions that are not conducive for use in an array formula are listed below with examples of workarounds for producing row-by-row results.

`and, avarage, count, countif, counta, concatenate & join, max & min`

The sample file with more examples:

[Make a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/copy)

## Sumif

`={"Mmult" ; MMULT(FILTER(B2:H * (B2:H = 3), A2:A<>"") , ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:H1)^0))) }`

`Mmult` function works slow, but I can't find a better solution.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank you so much. This works perfectly: ={"Mmult" ; MMULT(FILTER(B2:H * (B2:H = 3), A2:A<>"") , ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:H1)^0))) }